Time-dependent hamiltonian eigenstates
I want to derive a general expression for the arbitrary state of a system, once an external disturbance becomes present, which previously wasn't. At the same time I want to know if there is an expression that relates Hamiltonian eigenstates of the system before the disturbance and after it, as it wasn't shown in my lecture.
Case 1: $H=H_0$/$H=H_0 + V$, where $V\neq V(t)$.
Case 2: $H=H_0+V(t)$.
I am considering the following scenario: $t_0\longrightarrow t'=t_a\longrightarrow t$.
So, initially we have a system, and we start the observation at some arbitrary time $t_0\neq 0$. One could write for an arbitrary state $\psi$:
$$\psi(\vec r,t')=\sum_{n,\tau}c_{n,\tau}(t_0)e^{-i\frac{E_n}{\hbar}(t'-t_0)}|\phi_{n,\tau}\rangle$$ where $|\phi_{n,\tau}\rangle$ is meant to represent an eigenstate of $H_0$ corresponding to the degenerate eigenvalue $n$. $\tau$ is meant to represent that, degeneracy.
At time $t'=t_a$ (activation time) the potential becomes present. This represents the initial time once we start operating with the potential present. So we write (lecture notes):
$$|\bar \psi(\vec r,t)\rangle=\sum_{\bar n,\tau}c_{n,\tau}(t_a)e^{-i\frac{\bar E_\bar n}{\hbar}(t-t_a)}|\bar \phi_{n,\tau}\rangle$$
Couple of points to make here:

We are assuming that the time it takes for the potential to activate, is way smaller in value than the time necessary for the system to adapt to the new setup. That is why, the initial state of the system once the potential is turned on is the same as the state of it prior to the potential being activated, in other words $\bar \psi(\vec r,t_a)=\psi(\vec t,r')$
In the lecture notes $c_{n,\tau}(t_a)$ is actually written as $\langle \bar n|\bar\psi(0)\rangle$. So in the lecture $t_a=0$, it completely disregards what happened before the switching on of the potential and $\phi_{n,\tau}\rightarrow n$. It doesn't consider degeneracy. I do, just so I can derivate a more general expression, which can be simplified if degeneracy is not considered.

Then we can continue as follows:
$$|\bar \psi(\vec r,t)\rangle=\sum_{\bar n,\tau}\langle \bar \phi_{\bar n,\tau}|\bar\psi(t_a)\rangle e^{-i\frac{\bar E_\bar n}{\hbar}(t-t_a)}|\bar \phi_{n,\tau}\rangle$$
Because of point 1 : $|\bar\psi(\vec r,t_a)= \psi(\vec r,t')$, then:
$$|\bar \psi(\vec r,t)\rangle=\sum_{\bar n,\tau}\langle \bar \phi_{\bar n,\tau}|\psi(\vec r,t')\rangle e^{-i\frac{\bar E_\bar n}{\hbar}(t-t_a)}|\bar \phi_{n,\tau}\rangle$$
Knowing the expression for $\psi(\vec r,t')$ and substituting it in the above expression, we get:
$$|\bar \psi(\vec r,t)\rangle=\sum_{\bar n,\tau}\langle \bar \phi_{\bar n,\tau}|\sum_{n,\tau}c_{n,\tau}(t_0)e^{-i\frac{E_n}{\hbar}(t'-t_0)}|\phi_{n,\tau}\rangle e^{-i\frac{\bar E_\bar n}{\hbar}(t-t_a)}|\bar \phi_{n,\tau}\rangle$$.
My questions are only 2:

How to simplify the above expression?
How can I find an expression for $|\bar \phi_{\bar n,\tau}\rangle$?


As you probably noted, the answer of question 1 are strong related to the answer of your second question. In perturbation theory, it is fundamental to know how the eigenstates before perturbation $\left|\phi_{n,\tau}\right>$ are related to the eigenstates $\left|\overline{\phi}_{n,\tau}\right>$. In order to do so, there are some possibilities:

If $V\neq V(t)$ and the Hamiltonian is nondegenerate the eigenstates $\left|\overline{\phi}_{n}\right>$ does not vary on time (neither $E_{n}$), so we expand the new states in terms of the older ones. This procedure is easier if we consider the perturbation $V = \epsilon W$, for some small parameter $\epsilon$ and we expand $\overline E_n = E_n + \epsilon E^1_n + \epsilon^2 E^2_n +\dots $ and $\left|\overline{\phi}_{n}\right>= \left|\phi_{n}\right> + \epsilon  \left|\phi_{n}^1\right>+ \epsilon^2 
\left|\phi_{n}^2\right>+ \dots $. The correction terms $E^j_n$ and $\left|\phi_{n}^j\right>$ are calculated recursively and the procedure is quite long. This procedure generally works well for small $\epsilon$ and it relies in the hypothesis that perturbed eigenstates are "near" the non perturbed ones.

If $V\neq V(t)$ but you have degeneracy, the procedure is similar, but know you should take care that the perturbation could be break the degeneracy.

If $V=V(t)$, the least procedure is not useful, since perturbed eigenvalues and eigenvectors vary on time. However, in this case, usually it is considered the product $\left<\psi(t_0)|\psi(t)\right>$ where the initial state is some specific no perturbed eigenvector and the posterior state is calculated through time evolution operator.

For slow varying $V(t)$, we also have the adiabatic theorem, for which we in principle could calculate explicitly the perturbed eigenstates. I think this case fits better in your case. In this case, $\left|\phi_{n,\tau}\right>$ and $\left|\overline\phi_{n,\tau}\right>$ differ from a phase that we call geometric phase.


In summary, there is no general procedure to approach your second question. It depends to what order you need to expand or what information do you need to obtain about your system
